# concatenated id on b-modal doesnt work (vue and bootstrap-vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I have the following code:

```
<template v-for="(element, index) in tableData">
  <tr>
      <template v-for="field in element">

        <template v-if="typeof field==='object'">
          <td v-for="nestedObjectValue in field">
            {{nestedObjectValue}}
          </td>
        </template>

        <template v-else>
          <td>
            {{field}}
          </td>
        </template>

      </template>
      <td><button v-on:click="changeRecord">Aendern</button></td>
      <td>
        <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Launch demo modal </b-button>

        <b-modal :id="'modal_' + index" title="BootstrapVue">
          <p class="my-4">Hello from modal dynam!</p>
        </b-modal>
      </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

my `<b-modal></b-modal>` shall receive an ID concatenated from "modal_" and "index". Index is taken from this v-for loop `<template v-for="field in element">`.
This works, to a degree. 
I can inspect the modals with the vue dev tools, here is a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKYpi.jpg

Here you can see that the id property was set accordingly. 
However, when I click the buttons, no modal appears.

The modal functionality works.
For example, If I give the modals a static id like this:

```
<div>
  <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>Launch demo modal</b-button>

  <b-modal id="modal-1" title="BootstrapVue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

They work. If they all have the same id, they all trigger when hitting just one button ^^ 
but they work. 
Why don't they work when I assigned them unique IDs this way?
What am I missing?

Comment: shouldnt `:id="'modal_' + index"` be `:id="'modal-' + index"`

Comment: Holy curb it works, thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

Rename: `:id="'modal_' + index"` to `:id="'modal-' + index"`